# call function which inside function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function, loading

I have a function to animate spinner inside my view, and inside this function I added two functions to start and stop the animation whenever needed, I need to call the function inside this main function, is there a way to achieve it?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   
        SpinnerAnimiation()

    }
   

    fileprivate func SpinnerAnimiation() {
            let loading = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: .zero, type: .ballBeat, color: .blue, padding: 0)
            loading.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(loading)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                loading.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
                loading.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
                loading.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
                loading.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
            ])
            
            func start() {
                loading.startAnimating()
            }
            
            func stop() {
                loading.stopAnimating()
            }
         
        }
```

Comment: Move the functions out of the `SpinnerAnimation` function, otherwise they can only be called from code inside that function. Also, functions should start with a lower case letter

Comment: If you want to call the functions from inside SpinnerAnimiation() you need to declare them at the top of the function. So move them before `let loading...`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I moved them above, but how can I call them from outside?

Comment: Mong them there won't help. You need to move the outside of the function so that they are just functions of your view controller.

Comment: My advice was only for when you wanted to call them from _inside_ the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way to do it is declare UI element as a property of the UIViewController, configure this element and then have two functions to operate it inside UIViewController.

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
   private let loading = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: .zero, type: .ballBeat, color: .blue, padding: 0)

   private func configureLoading() {
       loading.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(loading)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                loading.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
                loading.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
                loading.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
                loading.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
            ])
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureLoading()
   }

   private func start() {
      loading.startAnimating()
   }
            
   private func stop() {
       loading.stopAnimating()
   }
     
}
```

Comment: @ Sergei Sevriugin is it possible to use it as extension? so I can use it on any view on the app ?

Comment: Sure you can create UIViewController extension to use this logic

Answer (score 1):

you can use extension for add loading view and call start or stop animation
for find NVActivityIndicatorView with tag inside viewController:

```
extension UIViewController {
    
    public func addLoadingView() {
        
        // check view with tag
        guard self.view.viewWithTag(9876) == nil else {
            return
        }
        
        let loading = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: .zero, type: .ballBeat, color: .blue, padding: 0)
        loading.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // set custom tag for prevent add twice
        loading.tag = 9876
        
        self.view.addSubview(loading)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            loading.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            loading.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            loading.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            loading.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    public func startLoading() {
        guard let loadingView = self.view.viewWithTag(9876) as? UIView else {
            return
        }
        
        loadingView.startAnimation()
    }
    
    public func stopLoading() {
        guard let loadingView = self.view.viewWithTag(9876) as? UIView else {
            return
        }
        
        loadingView.stopAnimation()
    }
}
```

and Use like this:

```
public class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.addLoadingView()
        self.stopLoading()
        self.startLoading()
    }
}
```